# Can a POST request be made server side?

Tags: javascript, server, axios, graphql, middleware

I am designing a middleware between the client and the GraphQL API. The idea is to create a route that all client requests go to first `/filament`. This route then decides whether it can send data back from the cache or to proceed on to `/graphql` to access the resolvers there to get data from the database. I am using Axios to make my requests but it isn't firing server side. I wanted to ask if this was just an improper way to use Axios or if I am doing it incorrectly.

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const redis = require("redis");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
// const REDIS_PORT = process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379;
//Create Redis client on Redis port (optional)
const client = redis.createClient();
const schema = require('./schema');
const bluebird = require('bluebird')
const app = express()

// bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
// bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);
app.use(express.json())

client.on("error", err => {
  console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Redis client connected');
});
// pass redis as context so our schema can use Redis methods

const wrapper = require('./filamentMiddleware')

app.use('/filament',
  wrapper(client), // filamentMiddleware with access to client
)

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP((req) => ({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: {
      client,
      req: req
    }
  })),
  // addToCacheWrapper(res.data)
);

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`GraphQL server is running on port: ${PORT}`)
);
```

Middleware

```
const axios = require('axios')
const serverFilamentQuery = require('./serverFilamentQuery')
const mergeDataFromCacheAndServer = require('./mergeDataFromCacheAndServer')

const wrapper = (client) => (req, res, next) => {
  const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
  client.get(ip, (err, cacheData) => {
    const { query } = req.body
    // ip not found in cache
    if (!cacheData) {
      console.log('cacheData:', cacheData)
      axios.post('/graphql', { query }).then(res => {
        console.log('have we made the post ????')
        // set redis cache
        // set the new data in Redis
        client.set(ip, JSON.stringify({
          todos: res.data.data['todos']
        }), (err, result) => {
          console.log(result)
        })

        const { data } = res.data
        // return combinedData to client
        return res.status(200).json({ data })
      })
    }
    // console.log('ip found in cache')
    const [newQuery, data, isMatched] = serverFilamentQuery(query, cacheData)

    if (isMatched) {
      return res.status(200).json({ data })
    } else {
      axios.post('/graphql', { newquery }).then(res => {
        const merged = mergeDataFromCacheAndServer(data['todos'], res.data.data['todos']);
        // set the new data in Redis
        console.log(merged)
        client.set(ip, JSON.stringify({
          todos: merged
        }), (err, result) => {
          console.log(result)
        })
        // return combinedData to client
        return res.status(200).json({ merged })
      })
    }
  })
}


module.exports = wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no problem making a post request server-side with Axios.

As per the [Axios GitHub page](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios)

> Promise based HTTP client for the *browser* and *node.js* *(ie. server-side)*

Note that the server-side call/usage is slightly different though, as per the [docs here](https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs)

versus client-side call [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation. It looks like to make a request in node.js, it requires you to use a full URI. I am trying to make the post to ```/graphql``` and am not sure how to access the full URI. I would love any pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Can't you just use the URI of your own host server (wherever your backend is running) and just append the required GraphQL end-point to be called?